# How to filter a JSON return from Json.Encode(Model)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, infragistics

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var myViewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    $("#grid1").igGrid({
        columns: [
        { headerText: "Entry ID", key: "entryid", dataType: "number" },
        { headerText: "TimeStamp", key: "timestamp", dataType: "date", format: "dateTime" },
        { headerText: "Category", key: "category", dataType: "string" },
        { headerText: "Message", key: "message", dataType: "string" }
    ],
        width: '100%',
        dataSource: myViewModel
    });
});
```

I need to filter `myViewModel` before passing it to igGrid as a datasource, but how can I achieve that?

There is only one Action Index() in  HomeController and all the data is being fetched here.

Most probably I am missing something here but I can't put my finger on it

```
 var sn=(from s in db.logentries select new{ s.accountid, s.servername}).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach(var sa in sn){
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = sa.servername.ToString(), Value = sa.accountid.ToString() });
        }    
        ViewBag.ServerName = items;
        ///////////////////////////////////
        var aid = (from s in db.logentries select new { s.accountid}).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> aidItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var sa in sn)
        {
            aidItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = sa.accountid.ToString(), Value = sa.accountid.ToString() });
        }
        ViewBag.accountID = aidItems;
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        var ct = (from s in db.categories select new { s.entryid, s.category1 }).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> ctItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var sa in ct)
        {
            ctItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = sa.category1.ToString(), Value = sa.entryid.ToString() });
        }
        ViewBag.Category = ctItems;
        ///////////////////////////////////////////
        var pn = (from s in db.logentries select new { s.entryid, s.processname }).ToList();
        List<SelectListItem> pnItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach (var sa in pn)
        {
            pnItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = sa.processname.ToString(), Value = sa.entryid.ToString() });
        }
        ViewBag.processName = pnItems;
        ViewBag.LogerID = db.logentries.ToList();
        return View(db.logentries.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I can think of, one is filtering your model in the Action method, or doing a javascript based filtering. Probably the best approach would be to retrieve the model you want through RESTful calls to your controller.

Comment: Can you please give me an example

Comment: Can you edit your question with the action methods being called? This would help understanding your need.